# Deny all access to WCF service via IIS not working when called via a website over TCP

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis, tcp

I have built a website and a WCF service. The website calls the WCF service (an application underneath the website) to get data. This connection is made using netTcpBinding (it _should be netNamedPipes but for some reason this refuses to work (only) on the deployment server, so I'm using TCP/IP).
In IIS (7.5) I have used IP Address and Domain Restrictions to deny all unspecified clients to the WCF service. I can see the change reflected in my web.config and I am unable to browse to the WCF service (403.6 Forbidden screen appears).

The problem is that the website is able to connect to the WCF service and get data even when I specify NO IP address is allowed i.e. no matter what I change, the website can still call the WCF service.

Why can the website access the WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make those same IP restrictions on your website? Since your website is the one calling the WCF service, making those same IP restrictions there would make sense also.

Comment: No sorry it doesn't make any sense. The website needs to be accessible by anyone. The WCF service, which connects to the database, must only be accessible by the website because that is the only client I trust (I do not want anybody with a web browser calling the WCF service, for example).

Comment: Then you should be able to make a IP filter on the WCF service. That way the only IP that can access the WCF service is the IP of the website OR, you could use token authentication, where you would only give the token to the website.

Comment: Yes you're right, I can do IP filtering in code if I wanted but IIS offers me a way to deny all access to unlisted IP addresses. What I'm asking is why this feature is not working for my WCF service marked as an application underneath another application (my website).